# find all values of k for which A is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\begin{bmatrix}
k &k  &0 \\ 
k^2 &2  &k \\ 
 0& k & k
\end{bmatrix}$

what I did is find the det first: 
$$\det= k(2k-k^2)-k(k^3-0)-0(k^3 -0)=2k^2-k^3-k^4$$

when $det = 0$  the matrix isn't invertible

$$2k^2-k^3-k^4=0$$
$$k^2(k^2 +k-2)=0$$
$$k^2+k-2=0$$
$$(k+2)(k-1)=0$$
$k = -2$ or $k = 1$.

I am lost here how to find the value for k when the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Assuming your calculations are correct: the matrix is invertible iff its determinant isn't zero iff $k\not \in \{-2,0,1\}$. What is your problem?

Comment: the question want me to find every value for k which the matrix is invertible. The things I've done above is for $k=-2 $and $k =1$ is when the matrix isn't invertible. well, how do I find k values for the matrix is invertible?

Comment: As mentioned below, you forgot $k=0$. Once you incorporate this, you can answer the question by noting that in the above argument you actually have equivalences, the statements go both ways. Thus if $k\not \in \{-2, 0, 1\}$, the matrix is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to consider $k = 0$.

$$k^2(k^2 +k-2)=0 \iff k^2(k+2)(k-1) = 0 \iff k \in \{-2, 0, 1\}$$

The matrix is invertible for all real (or complex) values $k$, except for $k \in\{-2, 0, 1\}$.

Comment: so I dont actually need to find the $k $values for the matrix is invertible. The answer is when$ k$ isn't $-2,0,1$ the matrix is invertible?

Comment: @user136877 Yes. All other cases.

Comment: Simply write $k \in \mathbb R \setminus\{-2, 0, 1\}$ or $k\in\mathbb C \setminus \{-2, 0, 1\}$: The matrix is invertible for all real (or complex) values $k$, except for $k \in\{-2, 0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\det(A)=- (k + 2)(k - 1)k^2$, hence the matrix is invertible if and only if this is nonzero, i.e., if not $k=0$, or $k=1$ or $k=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all square matrices are invertible. It is very special, i.e. singular, for a square matrix to be non-invertible. As you say, $\det = 2k^2-k^3-k^4$. This factorises to give $k^2(2+k)(1-k)$.

Your matrix is invertible for all values of $k$ except $k=0$, $k=-2$ or $k=1$. The matrix is invertible for all of the other values of $k$. There are three isolated values that make the matrix non-invertible. We can let $k$ be any complex number, i.e. $k$ can belong to an infinite, two-dimensional plane. out of all of the infinite points in the complex plane, only three isolated points give a singular matrix.